# php - Getting value from array in a for loop to use in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What I have is a custom admin page within Wordpress where the user can add names/titles/mp3's which all gets entered into the database. On the same page, I also have it select all the entries from the database and list them with checkboxes next to them and I'm trying to get it to delete the checked entries from the database using an array. This what I have so far:

```
$songs = $_POST['song'];
    $num = count($songs);
    for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM song_list WHERE title = '".$songs[]."'";
        echo $sql;
      var_dump($songs);
    }
```

When I dump `$songs`, it has all the correct data, but when I try to pull it and add it to the query, I keep getting nothing. It's not an associative array, so I tried `$songs[0]` and `$songs[1]`, but I get nothing.

Any insight would be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:**
var_dump
`array(3) { ["Forget You"]=> string(2) "on" ["DJ Got Us Falling in Love"]=> string(2) "on" ["Blurred Lines"]=> string(2) "on" }`

Also, I tried adding `$i` ($songs[$i]). It just comes out as `title = ''`

Comment: Can you update the question with the var_dump please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing the array index:

```
$songs[$i]
```

Turns into:

```
$songs = $_POST['song'];
    $num = count($songs);
    for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM song_list WHERE title = '".$songs[$i]."'";
        echo $sql;
    }
```

An more elegant way is to use a `foreach` loop:

```
$songs = $_POST['song'];
foreach($songs as $song) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM song_list WHERE title = '".$song."'";
    echo $sql;
}
```

An even more elegant way is to use prepared statements (with PDO):

```
// Prepare statement
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM song_list WHERE title = :song');

$songs = $_POST['song'];
foreach($songs as $song) {
    // Bind and execute
    $stmt->bindParam(':song', $song);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Using the foreach instead of the count/for did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it much simpler and shorter - **one-liner** :)

```
$sql =  "DELETE FROM song_list " .
        "WHERE title IN ('" . implode("','", $_POST['song']) . "')";
```

**Things to note:**

- Be aware of SQL injection attacks - never ever concatenate user input strings ($_GET, $_POST etc.) directly into SQL!
- Deleting by title is very bad solution, because if you'll have in title for example symbol `'`, then your SQL will break. That's why in SQL `id` fields are invented :)

Comment: This is the best solution if you want to delete everything as one "transaction". If you want to handle potential errors on a row/record level, use my solution :-)

Comment: Good point regarding the "delete by title". I think I'll pull the ID into the checkbox value and grab that instead. I already have an ID column anyway. It's a habit to ALWAYS have that :)

Comment: Exactly - always use `id`s and always escape user input variables to avoid SQL injection attacks. If you do so, you'll be safe and happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding $i to your array and you will get the value at the given place.
But you can write your code like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['song']) {
    foreach($_POST['song'] as $key => $title) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM song_list WHERE title = '".$title."'";
        echo $sql;
    }
}
```